# Application crashes while using SDWebImageCache in IOS 9 in tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios8, afnetworking, ios9, sdwebimage

i am using SDWebImageCache for loading thumbnail images in UITableview custom cell. But in ios 9 the application crashes when i scroll the UITable. Similar is the case with AFNetworking too(UIIMageView + AFNetworking) class.

**The class which i used from SDWebImageCache is:**

```
[cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:imageLoadUrl
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"*placeholder image*"]
                             options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

**The class which i used from UIIMageView + AFNetworking is:**

```
        [cell.imgMain setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl]
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wachizLogoIcon.png"]
                              success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                  cell.imgMain.image=image;
                              }
                              failure:nil];
```

But still the application crashes and shows the following screen:

[APPLICATION CRASHES IN IOS 9 and sometimes for IOS 8.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTruM.png)

Please help me from this situation. Lots of pressure ...

Answer (score 1):

```
use this code

NSMutableArray *Imagedata;

 - 

NSString *Banner = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[imagedata valueForKey:@""]]objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
 NSLog(@"%@",Banner); 
[cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Banner] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placehoder2.jpg"]];
```

---

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Comment: for example you want all the images in tableview cell so first take all the image in nsmutablearray after that  use NSString and value for key and give the using ObjectAtIndex path like:                                              NSString *Banner = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[imagedata valueForKey:@""]]objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];              
 NSLog(@"%@",Banner);    After that String paste in  that line [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Banner] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placehoder2.jpg"]];

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide the information there to make it more visible to others that are seeking for answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue once. It was basically a low memory crash when the SDWebImageCache tries to cache images. Try implementing `didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods to debug it. Reset the cache on low memories. Also set a maxCacheSize for your images.
These methods didn't worked out well for me so i switched to [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke). Still I had to set diskCapacity to a certain limit.

Answer (score 0):

When u cache an image this will store in your device RAM... please check your RAM in debugger...if you cache lots of image this will terminate app due to Memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

add code to Appdelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Clearing cache-------------");


[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] cleanDisk];
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearDisk];
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setValue:nil forKey:@"memCache"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"cache cleared"
                                                    message:Nil
                                                   delegate:Nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```